# server for testing

Tags: java, apache, http, sockets, port

I'm given some nasty task in concurrent programming.
I need to continuously read data from source address then upload the data via HTTP protocol to the target address and I do that multi-threaded.

How can i test it?
Is there some site i can freely connect to and read to them?
Or how can i do it (preferred easily) with my own computer?
I heard the words(Apache server something..)

Thank u (in advance for your kind help).

Oh and I'm doing it as a Java console application.

I will be happy for a direction where to read about that too.

Comment: as an actual answer: you can write tiny supplementary test script which will write some data to your proxy program constantly. Actually, in Unix environment it can be done in command-line.

Comment: What do you mean? For instance, do you want to find something that will generate your source content or something that will enable you to read what ends up on the target? Or both? Also, what OS?

Comment: i can write the content myself.. i just need a place to write to(and from).

Comment: What do you mean "upload via HTTP to the target"? A web service? You don't "push" content to the client; the client must request the page.

Comment: @toto2 I guess he means uploading via POST or PUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you heard about is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), an open source Java web server; it's very easy to set up, just follow the instructions on the site; a similar alternative is [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). Of course what you actually do with them once they are running it's all up to you.

Comment: I would recommend OP to stay away from anything more complex than telnet/netcat until he understands them fully. Then, he can move on to real HTTP server, like Apache HTTPd. And after that, to the Java servlets. Btw, OP didn't state explicitly he needs Java-based solution.

Comment: @user1090419 yes, it works for windows. But, at first, pay attention to my comment above and ask yourself if isn't it more wise to start with something less complex, is it?

Comment: hell i don't know.. I'M afraid this task is a little bit to much for me..:(

Comment: @VictorSorokin true, he doesn't need a Java/servlet server, but I can't honestly see Tomcat being more complex than HTTPd or Linux terminal juggling; since he only needs a basic local setup he has to do little more than unzipping and running. From a learning point of view he clearly need to start from the ground up, but to get up and running he doesn't need to know much.

Comment: Servlet container has lot more behind the scenes to make it work properly, when compared against Apache Httpd. When they break, it can be lot harder to understand what to fix. That's the reason I made my recommendation.

Comment: I still think use telnet to provide source data and write your own socket client to sit on a port and log data received. Bit old-school but a really good learning experience that demystifies the workings of computer networking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you on Unix, here's sample one-liner which will greet incoming TCP connection (from your program, for example) and exit afterwards immediately, using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

```
netcat -l -p 40000 -c 'echo "Hello, stranger"'
```

Try to use it via

```
telnet localhost 40000
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use telnet to write data to your port. This would enable you to test your reader (i.e. generate source data).

To read it, why not use a port monitor? Or, write your own little socket client to log what's received. Sounds like a good exercise for your particular problem.